# How to do a foreach loop with an object in laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

does someone can help me to show me how can I make a loop if my object is just like this `assigned: "["741852963","79545236","7845120"]"`

I try with

```
$assigned = array();
    foreach($project->assigned as $arrayItem){

        $user = Admin::select('name', 'numero_empleado')->where('numero_empleado', $arrayItem)->get();
        $assigned =  $user;
    }
return $assigned;
```

but that way throw me an error

`"Invalid argument supplied for foreach()"`

I want to add the result in other array to send to the front

Comment: `$project->assigned` looks like a string representation of an array... Which is not valid in a `foreach()` loop. Run `dd(is_string($project->assigned));`; if that says `true`, then that's your issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to first `json_decode`

```
$myData = json_decode($project->assigned);
```

Then use `foreach`

```
foreach($myData as $arrayItem){

    $user = Admin::select('name', 'numero_empleado')->where('numero_empleado', $arrayItem)->get();
    $assigned =  $user;
}
```

Comment: Not only that, but he has also to set that attribute as an Array [casting](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-mutators#array-and-json-casting) it...

Answer (score 0):

You have to convert string array into array , you can use `json_decode` method like:-

```
$assigned = json_decode($assigned);
```